# how to cache my website?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, caching, header

morning,

I have few questions about caching a website, since I haven't tried caching a site before. 
First is how to cache a site so it will have a faster loading when clients browse the site. For example I have many images in my css style, how do I cache this? From what I've read before caching in php is done through the 'head' tag and also caching can be done in the .htaccess (glad I'm using htaccess ^_^).

I added this tags in my header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">//or content="cache"???
```

Also this is what's inside my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>    
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance, will frequently visit, I really like to learn how to cache :)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As images and other media files to not get processed by php, this is more related to the web-server that you are using so you might want to check on serverfault.com or at least change the php tag for the web-server you are using.

To answer your question; I don't know if the syntax in an `.htaccess` file would be the same, but in my apache `httpd.conf` file I use the following to tell the visitors browser to cache images for 20 weeks (12096000 seconds):

```
# Set up caching on media files for 20 weeks
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$">
ExpiresDefault A12096000
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: thank you for the response @jeroen. Should I move this question to the serverfault? question about the httpd.conf, if the site is uploaded in the client server then I would have to put this syntax to their httpd.conf. right? hmmm, any other way that this?

Comment: @Wondering Coder I haven't tried it, but you can easily check if this block works in an `.htaccess` file as well. Using the pagespeed extension you can check if the browser receives the right header / expiration time.

Comment: tried to used the speed test in google but their are conflicts about the google that I'm using. Currently i'm using the google beta channel and for the speed test of the google to work I must use their dev channel chrome. Do you any speed test @jeroen?

Comment: @Wondering Coder I use the pagespeed extension (with Firebug...) in Firefox.